# How do I change the company country when signing up for Facebook Credits?

Tags: facebook

I want to update the country listed on my company using Facebook Credits, but can't find out where to do that.

Where are the settings that I need to update or change for country location so that I can have the Facebook Credits attached to my company at the proper locale?